# Increase right margin of header

Tags: fancyhdr

I want to include a graphic into the header but this should be placed outside the page margins. I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=4.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm,  showframe]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{61pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-61.0pt}
\rhead{
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{MyLogo}}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
    \kant[1-8]
\end{document}
```

So the logo ends at the frame, i.e. `4.5cm` from the right page. But I would like to shift the logo so it ends with a distance to the right paper frame of `2.5cm`.

I didn't find any solutions.

Using `luatex 1.13.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it with `picture`environment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=4.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{61pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-61.0pt}

\rhead{
    \begin{picture}(0,0) \put (0,0){
            \includegraphics[height=2cm]{MyLogo}} 
    \end{picture}
}

\begin{document}
    \kant[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Ohhh.. that's lovely. I like this approach. Thank you very much :-)